# Switching tabbar without refreshing UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In my application 5 tabs are there. In each tab I am pushing another UIViewController for RootViewController. Now If I switch tabs. It will show RootViewController itself. When Switching between tab bars I dont want go to show RootViewController. Can you tell me how can I do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what it means that "Switching between tab bars".

I think it helps you.

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

if return NO, tabBarController doesn't move tab itself.
Default: retun YES

If return YES, tabBarController calls

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually my question was not clear. Let me ask you once again.

Comment: In my application 5 tabs are there. In 1st tab.There is a root view controller. Which as one button on clicking that button one UIViewController will be pushed. Now i will go to another tab and come back to 1st tab(previous tab). Now here it is showing rootviewController.(I don't want this.) Root view Controller should not pop pushed UIViewControllers.